# Advertising Studio Audience - Contact not matched

Tags: marketing-cloud, audience, advertising-studio

Does anyone know what happens to a contact sent through Advertising Studio Audience to FB if not matched on their side?

Does FB (Meta) delete the contact on their side and sends feedback to Salesforce?

Thx for the answers.

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 0):

Meta does nothing with an unmatched contact. Keep in mind, that Advertising Studio integration only shares hashed data (email/phone) with Meta, meaning that no contact gets created in their end, in case this hashed identifier cannot be matched. Imagine following scenario:

| **SFMC Email** | **SFMC Hash** | **FB Hash** | **FB Email** | **Match** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| john.doe@example.com | 8eb1b522f60d11fa897de1dc6351b7e8 | 8eb1b522f60d11fa897de1dc6351b7e8 | john.doe@example.com | YES |
| foo.bar@example.com | a7440323a684ea47406313a33156e5e9 | a7440323a684ea47406313a33156e5e9 | foo.bar@example.com | YES |
| sales.force@example.com | 29a31f655489ca4f412ce84c35c621c8 |  |  | NO |

You have an audience of 3 in your Advertising Studio, which will expose the hashed email addresses to Meta. In first two cases, there is already an FB account using the same email address. Given that FB and Advertising Studio are using the same hashing algorithm, the hashed values generated on both sides will be the same, and we can identify these individuals across SFMC and FB.

In the last case, you have an email address in SFMC, which you send to FB in it's hashed version. As FB does not have a corresponding hash in it's own end, it will not be able to match this contact. A hash is a one-way function only, so even though FB received a hashed value of an email address, it is not possible in any way to decipher this, and identify the email address which has been hashed.

So you should not worry about handling of PII in Advertising Studio integration, as it will not expose any clear text email addresses to Meta.